# Remove collection through API in Fauna

Tags: faunadb

Header says it all. Is there a way to delete/remove/drop a collection in FaunaDB through the API?

I've tried to look through all of the listed functions but I hope I've missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. `Delete($ref)` where `$ref` is something like `Collection("foo")` will delete all the documents in the named collection.

Full docs for `Delete` are [here](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/delete).

There is also an [example provided](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/crud_examples#collection-delete), as eskwayrd points out.